# Dictionary ContainsKey and get value in one function

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is there a way to call `Dictionary<string, int>` once to find a value for a key? Right now I'm doing two calls like.

```
if(_dictionary.ContainsKey("key") {
 int _value = _dictionary["key"];
}
```

I wanna do it like:

```
object _value = _dictionary["key"] 
//but this one is throwing exception if there is no such key
```

I would want null if there is no such key or get the value with one call?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx)

```
int value;
bool exists = _dictionary.TryGetValue("key", out value);
```

`TryGetValue` returns true if it contains  the specified key, otherwise, false.

Comment: `TryGetValue` will return true if the dictionary contained an element with that key, otherwise false.

Comment: what if he has a key/value pair like {"key",0},and he tries to get the value from a non-existing key the int value will be 0.

Comment: @terrybozzio in that case `exists` will be `false`

Answer (score 9):

The selected answer the correct one. This is to provider user2535489 with the proper way to implement the idea he has:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions 
{
    public static TValue GetValue<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue fallback = default(TValue))
    {
        TValue result;

        return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out result) ? result : fallback;
    }
}
```

Which can then be used with:

```
Dictionary<string, int> aDictionary;
// Imagine this is not empty
var value = aDictionary.GetValue("TheKey"); // Returns 0 if the key isn't present
var valueFallback = aDictionary.GetValue("TheKey", 10); // Returns 10 if the key isn't present
```

Comment: There's still no means of knowing if you're getting a value from the dictionary or the fallback. I don't see any value in wrapping `TryGetValue` like this.

Comment: You are correct. But the user has the option to use `TryGetValue` if he cares to know if the key was in the dictionary. It's just syntactic sugar if he doesn't care to and want a one liner. I personnaly wouldn't use my proposition as I feel like I lose control. It's purely for the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

this should probably do it,for your purposes.
Like you asked in the question ,getting all in one go,null or the value,into an object:

```
object obj = _dictionary.ContainsKey("key") ? _dictionary["key"] as object : null;
```

or..

```
int? result = _dictionary.ContainsKey("key") ? _dictionary["key"] : (int?)null;
```

Comment: This is `O(|keys|)`. We can do better.

Comment: "key" is an example of a string as key in dictionary not the - get the keys -

Comment: I understand that. But `Enumerable.Where` will do a linear search over all of the keys. That's why it's linear in the number of keys. Denoting the number of keys by `|keys|` gives `O(|keys|)`.

Comment: And your edit expose the same problem. If "key" isn't in `_dictionary`, a `KeyNotFoundException` is thrown.

Comment: i see what you mean,i know and i was wrong because i understood the question wrongly,i thought he wanted to get the string of the key itself,in my edit i made what i think is what he wants

Comment: @terrybozzio: Now your answer is  simply wrong. `_dictionary["key"]` throws an exception if the key is not present. Have a look at the question.

Comment: new edit you guys where right,i really thought he wanted to get the value of a key that he knew existed,my bad,this should do right,i think.

Comment: if its for searching i think this is the way.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you could do something like this (or write a much clearer extension method).

```
        object _value = _dictionary.ContainsKey(myString) ? _dictionary[myString] : (int?)null;
```

I'm not sure I'd be particularly happy using that though, by combining the null and your "Found" condition, I would have thought you're just shifting the problem to a null check slightly further down the line.